# Substituting user inputs to STRING field in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a below snippet from my code which takes me to a particular path,
The 6th filed from my path i.e. Substitute1 is a dynamic value and name can change.
The other path names are static.

```
dir_path = ("/nfs/old_home/dexter/work/REISSUES/Substitute1/logs")
```

i can take a keyboard input using `raw_input(text)` ok, but how do i substitute that 6th Field i.e Substitute1 with the name i entered from keyboard, i mean its simple in shell as i just had to read the value and place a `$value(/nfs/old_home/dexter/work/REISSUES/$value/logs)` over the path there but can same be done using python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.format`

**Ex:**

```
folder = input("Enter Folder")
dir_path = "/nfs/old_home/dexter/work/REISSUES/{0}/logs".format(folder)
print(dir_path)
```

---

Python 3.6 and above `f-string`

**Ex:**

```
folder = input("Enter Folder")
dir_path = f"/nfs/old_home/dexter/work/REISSUES/{folder}/logs"
```